# A module or solution to build first time user walkthrough?

Tags: 7

Is there a module or existing solution out there that can be used to create first time user walkthroughs of a site? For example, a user logs in for the first time and gets redirected to a certain page and then can follow steps to learn the site etc etc. I have done some googling on the matter but as you can imagine the results are hold to filter when searching for terms like "guide", "walkthrough", "module", "new user" and so on...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [jQuery Joyride module](http://drupal.org/project/joyride) would certainly be an option

> This module provides Drupal integration with Zurb's Joyride Jquery plugin in order to provide a tour of different html elements on your Drupal site. Drupal integration is done via the Context module, which provides a way to control conditional calling of the joyride plugin and copy-and-paste method for adding specific tour code.

It wraps around the excellent [jQuery Joyride plugin](http://www.zurb.com/playground/jquery-joyride-feature-tour-plugin)

Comment: Damn clive you know the module repositories well!

Comment: Gotta confess...I only knew about Joyride, didn't know there was a Drupal module till I searched :P

Comment: And they had a konami code in their joyride!!! :)

Comment: I dont have to look any further. That module is awesome